# Get Only the Attachments from an E-mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a code which checks attachments of e-mail:

```
final Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
final int numAttachments = mp.getCount();
...
final Part part = mp.getBodyPart(attachmentNumber);
```

However, `numAttachments` return number of attachments + 1. When I iterate over `mp.getBodyPart(index)` I see that I iterate over attachments and e-mail. I just want to get attachments, not e-mails.

I know [that](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#attachments):

> Attachments will usually, but not always, have a Content-Disposition of attachment. Attachments will usually, but not always, have a file name.

When I test it, I see that e-mail is always at 0-th index and attachments comes after that. So, skipping the 0-th index may be a solution but I don't know is this valid for all e-mail servers.

How can I get only the attachments from an e-mail?

Comment: The notion of "attachment" isn't really defined. The multipart subtypes are defined, however, and will help you figure out how to handle the parts. For example, multipart/related and multipart/alternative are very different.

Comment: First index is always e-mail when I test it with Exchange but I want to be sure about it. There is an explanation `So, a good approach to start with is to only consider messages with a top level multipart/mixed content and then consider the parts after the first part to be attachments whether they say so or not.` here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#attachments Does it verify my suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simple case, a message of type multipart/mixed will have the first body part as the main content of the message and the other body parts as attachments.  The first body part may be a simple text/plain part, or it might be a multipart/alternative or multipart/related part.  But skipping the first body part will usually do what you want.

There are many more complex cases allowed by MIME.  You have to decide whether and how you want to handle those cases.  The most complex cases are signed and encrypted messages, but they're relatively rare.